# Library not found for -lMailCore-ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’m a beginner developper with swift. My compile is correct if I build with IOS simulator. If I build with Any IOS Device (arm64) or with my iPhone (SE) i’ve the same error :
***“Library not found for -lMailCore-ios”***
I work with Xcode 12.4 and swift 5.3 (I had the same error with Xcode 12.3).
I’ve tried also to had a Package.swift created with Xcode. And I’ve added a dependency with ***"https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2"***.
I’ve an error :
***"https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJGy.png) has no Package.swift manifest for version 0.6.4"***
I’ve looked at GitHub support help and stackoverflow but I’ve not found or not understood about this pb with MailCore2
I join captures of screens.
Thank you for your help

Comment: your pod file is correct for mailcore ?

Comment: I think, the content of my pod is :

Comment: I think, the content of my pod is : # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project 
platform :ios, '14.3'

target 'gfer94' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for gfer94
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database' 
pod 'mailcore2-ios', '~> 0.6'
end

Comment: did you try pod update ?

Comment: Yes also, i tried an pod update without success

Comment: This is the reason I tried also with package.swift

Comment: For information i've suppressed MailCore2, too difficult to use, and replaced it by skpsmtpmessage. Now it's correct!!